# Jaxb2 Custom Validation Messages, is possible?

Tags: validation, jaxb, unmarshalling, jaxb2

Anyone knows how to do custom validation messages with JaxB 2.x? My need is know which tag or object property caused the error. 
I already have a custom ValidationEventHandler, but the ValidationEvent event parameter of handleEvent method doesn't brings the Node information, just the line and column related with the error in XML document.
My intention is customize the unmarshal error messages with ones more user friendly. There is some way to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The [`javax.xml.bind.ValidationEventLocator`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/ValidationEventLocator.html) offers some information about the cause of the problem.

**Marshal Operation**

When a ValidationEvent is reported during a marshal operation the object related to the error should be available through:

```
validationEvent.getLocator().getObject();
```

**Unmarshal Operation**

When a ValidationEvent is reported during an unmarshal operation the corresponding DOM node may be returned if it is available (unlikely anything will be present on this property when unmarshalling from a source other than DOM nodes).

```
validationEvent.getLocator().getNode();
```

**For More Information**

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-marshalunmarshal-schema.html
- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/11/validate-jaxb-object-model-with-xml.html

---

**UPDATE**

You could do the following:

**Demo**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;

import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.UnmarshallerHandler;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import javax.xml.validation.Schema;
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;

import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        spf.setNamespaceAware(true);

        SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI); 
        Schema schema = sf.newSchema(new File("customer.xsd"));
        spf.setSchema(schema);

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        UnmarshallerHandler unmarshallerHandler = unmarshaller.getUnmarshallerHandler();

        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
        ContentAndErrorHandler contentErrorHandler = new ContentAndErrorHandler(unmarshallerHandler);
        xr.setErrorHandler(contentErrorHandler);
        xr.setContentHandler(contentErrorHandler);

        InputSource xml = new InputSource(new FileReader("input.xml"));
        xr.parse(xml);
    }

}
```

**ContentAndErrorHandler**

This class acts as both a ContentHandler and ErrorHandler.  This is so it can store the current node name for when the error happens.

```
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.ContentHandler;
import org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler;
import org.xml.sax.Locator;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;

public class ContentAndErrorHandler implements ContentHandler, ErrorHandler {

    private ContentHandler contentHandler;
    private String qname;
    private String namespaceURI;

    public ContentAndErrorHandler(ContentHandler contentHandler) {
        this.contentHandler = contentHandler;
    }

    public void characters(char[] arg0, int arg1, int arg2) throws SAXException {
        contentHandler.characters(arg0, arg1, arg2);
    }

    public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
        contentHandler.endDocument();
    }

    public void endElement(String arg0, String arg1, String arg2)
            throws SAXException {
        qname = arg2;
        namespaceURI = arg0;
        contentHandler.endElement(arg0, arg1, arg2);
    }

    public void endPrefixMapping(String arg0) throws SAXException {
        contentHandler.endPrefixMapping(arg0);
    }

    public void ignorableWhitespace(char[] arg0, int arg1, int arg2)
            throws SAXException {
        contentHandler.ignorableWhitespace(arg0, arg1, arg2);
    }

    public void processingInstruction(String arg0, String arg1)
            throws SAXException {
        contentHandler.processingInstruction(arg0, arg1);
    }

    public void setDocumentLocator(Locator arg0) {
        contentHandler.setDocumentLocator(arg0);
    }

    public void skippedEntity(String arg0) throws SAXException {
        contentHandler.skippedEntity(arg0);
    }

    public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
        contentHandler.startDocument();
    }

    public void startElement(String arg0, String arg1, String arg2,
            Attributes arg3) throws SAXException {
        qname = arg2;
        namespaceURI = arg0;
        contentHandler.startElement(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3);
    }

    public void startPrefixMapping(String arg0, String arg1)
            throws SAXException {
        contentHandler.startPrefixMapping(arg0, arg1);
    }

    public void error(SAXParseException arg0) throws SAXException {
        System.out.println("{" + namespaceURI + "}" + qname);
        arg0.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }

    public void fatalError(SAXParseException arg0) throws SAXException {
        System.out.println("{" + namespaceURI + "}" + qname);
        arg0.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }

    public void warning(SAXParseException arg0) throws SAXException {
        System.out.println("{" + namespaceURI + "}" + qname);
        arg0.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }

}
```

**Customer**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Customer {

    private String name;
    private List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers = new ArrayList<PhoneNumber>();

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="phone-number")
    public List<PhoneNumber> getPhoneNumbers() {
        return phoneNumbers;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumbers(List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers) {
        this.phoneNumbers = phoneNumbers;
    }

}
```

**PhoneNumber**

```
public class PhoneNumber {

}
```

**customer.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:element name="customer">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="name" type="stringWithMaxSize5" />
                <xs:element ref="phone-number" maxOccurs="2" />
             </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="phone-number">
        <xs:complexType />
    </xs:element>

    <xs:simpleType name="stringWithMaxSize5">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="5"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

**input.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customer>
   <name>Jane Doe</name>
   <phone-number/>
   <phone-number/>
   <phone-number/>
</customer>
```

**Output**

```
{}name
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-maxLength-valid: Value 'Jane Doe' with length = '8' is not facet-valid with respect to maxLength '5' for type 'stringWithMaxSize5'.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.elementLocallyValidType(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.processElementContent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at example.Demo.main(Demo.java:39)
{}name
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-type.3.1.3: The value 'Jane Doe' of element 'name' is not valid.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.elementLocallyValidType(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.processElementContent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at example.Demo.main(Demo.java:39)
{}phone-number
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'customer'. No child element '{phone-number}' is expected at this point.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.elementLocallyValidComplexType(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.elementLocallyValidType(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.processElementContent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at example.Demo.main(Demo.java:39)
```

Comment: Hi Blaise. I'm already try this methods but the `validationEvent.getLocator().getNode();` always return null in the unmarshal operation, even in your post has a question about how to make the `getNode()` method return a value but without answer. You know how to do that?

Comment: @avaz - There isn't a way to force the JAXB impl to return a node in the ValidationEventLocator.  However, I'll look at making this available in EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy).

Comment: @blaise there is a unofficial annotation `@XmlLocation` in jaxb-ri. The documentation of this annotations says that a field or method that have this annotation must be or receive a parameter of type Locator and the parser will set the Locator info of the object that is being parsed. Well, do you know how to use this annotation? :)

Comment: @avaz - I am not familiar with that annotation, but I do not believe it will give you what you want.  Assuming the it is org.xml.sax.Locator the only information contained there is: column number, line number, public ID, and System ID.  In the Javadoc comments on the source for @XmlLocator it says that the Locator will not be sent when unmarshalling from DOM nodes:  http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Modules-com.sun/xml/com/sun/xml/internal/bind/annotation/XmlLocation.java.htm

Comment: @blaise yeap, I read. So I think that for show a more user friendly message when unmarshal objects I will need to do my own SAXParser and implementing startElement, characters, endElement and go doing the parser and validation for every field. This is bad.

Comment: -- The JAXB docs of Unmarshaller.unmarshal(source) says about SAX 2.0 Parser Plugability: _The only way for a client application to specify an alternate parser mechanism to be used during unmarshal is via the unmarshal(SAXSource) API_. I try this but it only works for Error Handling and not for the parser process in fact, I think that could be a bug in the API, anyway I think that the JAXB don't offer a robust way to customize the validation messages.

Comment: @avaz - I have posted an example of how you could get the necessary details for your error message.

Comment: @blaise I'm currently analyzing your proposed solution, as soon as possible I give you a feedback.

Comment: @blaise thank you for your attention but unfortunately the proposed solution don't fit well to my requirements. My intention is be able to do really customizations in JAXB bindings error messages, and for that not only the name of field is needed but the invalid value too. I'm looking now at de [JSR303](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303) and [JAXB Customization Bindings](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html). The first one seems to be the one that fits well to me because when a validation fail they provide all info...

Comment: @blaise |cont|...necessary to do a really custom message. The JAXB Custom Bindings is nice too but has heavily need of schemas files with jaxb namespaces. If, in the future an integration with JAXB and JSR303 occur, the thing will be really nice and powerful. Anyway, thank you so much for your attention.